# Why does my R function works inside but not when called from outside?

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I have a R function which works when I select its commands and run them manually. The function manipulates a Dataframe. When called from outside, nothing changes in the dataframe?

My function:

```
fun <- function(){
  
  # If C2 value greater than 0 and less than 10 and C1 value is 1
  index <- DF$C2 < 10 & DF$C2 > 0 & DF$C1 == 1
  
  # Then increment C2 value by 1
  DF$C2[index] <-  DF$C2[index] + 1
  
  # Other logic
  DF_processed <- t(apply(DF[Index,], 1, someFun))
  DF[Index, ] <- DF_processed
  
  # If C2 value greater or equal to 10, reset C1,C2 to 0
  otherIndex <- DF$C2 >= 10 
  DF$C1[aboutToRecoverIndex] <- DF$C2[otherIndex] <- 0
  
}
```

This function works when I select all the lines inside and run it (RStudio) but not when doing the following:

```
fun() // This wont work
```

**My Dataframe:**

|  | C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 0 |

**Output from running function lines from inside:**

|  | C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 3 | 0 |

Output from calling fun()

|  | C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 0 |

Comment: you are not returning `DF` in your function, `DF` needs to be on the last line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign values using the `<-` operator, the values are assigned in the local environment - in your case, it is the environment in which the function `fun` is executed.`DF` is defined in the global environment, which is the parent environment of the function `fun`. In order to assign values in the parent environment, you need to do the assignments using the `<<-` operator.

See

```
?`<<-`
```

Comment: All true, but it's also worth mentioning that it's bad practice to modify global objects within a function.  It leads to confusion such as the OP's and limits the function's usability.  I believe a *better* solution is to pass the object to be modified as an argument to the function, and then to return the modified object from the function.

Comment: Thanks for this comment, I absolutely agree with you. I meant to give a technical explanation to the OP's question, but your comment is very true and important.

Comment: For some reason, using the <<- operator says DF not found.

Comment: And you are sure it is defined in the global environment? Can you access it from RStudio's console?